# Implement AutoFill Credential Provider Extension in iOS14

Tags: swift, swiftui, passwords, autofill, ios14

I'm trying to implement the AutoFill Credential Provider Extension, however I'm having some problems following [the video of the WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/721/#:%7E:text=Your%20app%20provides%20AutoFill%20a,or%20password%20field%20is%20focused.) where they presented this feature.

Is there someone that has already done it that could help me?

Right now, I added the AutoFill Credential Provider capability as well as the AutoFill Credential Provider extension, which right now looks like this:

```
import AuthenticationServices

class CredentialProviderViewController: ASCredentialProviderViewController {

    override func prepareCredentialList(for serviceIdentifiers: [ASCredentialServiceIdentifier]) {
    }
    
    override func provideCredentialWithoutUserInteraction(for credentialIdentity: ASPasswordCredentialIdentity) {
        let databaseIsUnlocked = true
        if (databaseIsUnlocked) {
            let passwordCredential = ASPasswordCredential(user: "j_appleseed", password: "apple1234")
            self.extensionContext.completeRequest(withSelectedCredential: passwordCredential, completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            self.extensionContext.cancelRequest(withError: NSError(domain: ASExtensionErrorDomain, code:ASExtensionError.userInteractionRequired.rawValue))
        }
    }

    override func prepareInterfaceToProvideCredential(for credentialIdentity: ASPasswordCredentialIdentity) {
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.extensionContext.cancelRequest(withError: NSError(domain: ASExtensionErrorDomain, code: ASExtensionError.userCanceled.rawValue))
    }

    @IBAction func passwordSelected(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        let passwordCredential = ASPasswordCredential(user: "j_appleseed", password: "apple1234")
        self.extensionContext.completeRequest(withSelectedCredential: passwordCredential, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

All of this was pre-written, but on the line

> } else {
>
> self.extensionContext.cancelRequest(withError: NSError(domain: ASExtensionErrorDomain, code:ASExtensionError.userInteractionRequired.rawValue))
>
> }

I get the yellow warning "Will never be executed". Can someone help me understand how this extension works? Or is there a guide that I can follow? I can't find any nor on this website nor elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: When you added this provider per the video, did you get the option on your device to select your extension as an autofill provider? I am having trouble connecting that dot.

Comment: @metamonkey @pandruz do you have a Demo app where it is working? I am following the video and I am not able to see the Autofill view controller 
I get the following error when tapping on the new AutoFill option from keyboard 
`Keyboard cannot present view controllers (attempted to present <UIKeyboardHiddenViewController_Autofill: 0x7fadddd15ec0>)`

Comment: @JERC I don't have a demo app, but the Autofill Credential Provider is working on my app. It's been a while since I implemented it, but I remember that in my case, once I managed to set the AppGroups correctly, it worked. Have you tried checking your AppGroups?

Comment: Hi gentlemen! The video linked is no longer available. By any change won't you have the video title so that i can google and see if i can find it somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

There's not much in the way of documentation or sample code, and no tutorials that I can find. Essentially there is the video you already linked to, and the documentation for the ASCredentialProviderViewController class, which is here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/ascredentialproviderviewcontroller?language=objc

But in your code, it should be quite clear why the line you quoted will never be executed. See my comments below:

```
let databaseIsUnlocked = true
if (databaseIsUnlocked)    //this is always true, because you've just set it to be true
    {
    let passwordCredential = ASPasswordCredential(user: "j_appleseed", password: "apple1234")
    self.extensionContext.completeRequest(withSelectedCredential: passwordCredential, completionHandler: nil)
    } else {               //so there is no "else"
        self.extensionContext.cancelRequest(withError: NSError(domain: ASExtensionErrorDomain, code:ASExtensionError.userInteractionRequired.rawValue))
    }
```

Presumably Apple thought people might want to replace "databaseIsUnlocked = true" with a check to see if their database is unlocked. If that doesn't apply to you, you can ignore that bit.

Comment: Yes, I couldn’t find much either! Thank you for your answer! I think I'll ignore that bit as you suggested